# Unity Error on creation of 3D URP project: "error CS0103: The name 'AdditionalGIBakeRequestsManager' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

Created a 3D URP project [Unity 2022.3.11f1], and while loading up the Unity editor, it made me open in safe mode. These 2 errors appeared in the console:

**Full errors:**

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.core@14.0.9\Runtime\Lighting\ProbeVolume\ProbeReferenceVolume.cs(651,13): error CS0103: The name 'AdditionalGIBakeRequestsManager' does not exist in the current context

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.core@14.0.9\Runtime\Lighting\ProbeVolume\ProbeReferenceVolume.cs(689,13): error CS0103: The name 'AdditionalGIBakeRequestsManager' does not exist in the current context
```

What can I do?

*Tried asking Windows Copilot; it told me to reimport URP package.. that didn't seem to be possible, so I deleted and readded it. Didn't work (same errors, though they were gone while the package was gone for obvious reasons). Deleted project and recreated; same error.*

Comment: Sometimes Unity does add in extra namespaces automatically and you have to remove them before building. However, if you actually want to use the experimental rendering package you need to add a `using` directive. Sorry if that's obvious, just a thought. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@12.1/api/UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.html. If you really can't solve it just make a new project with the assets and project settings folders.

Comment: Hello again! Forgot to mention I'm new to Unity, so your answer confused me quite a bit. To avoid hassling you, I did go and use external sources to make sense of your answer, and it does make a fair bit of sense now, and I've found the messed up variables in the ProbeVolume folder.. but I have no idea what to do with them. I'd rather not have experimental features, but what would I do in either scenario?

Comment: P.S. Any attempts to edit the erroneous .cs resulted in Unity getting mad and complaining about the last edited time being more recent, and trying to reimport that file or something

Comment: TutorialsPoint is a good site to learn: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_namespaces.htm. Bear in mind almost all code you will (Unity, normal C#) all has a namespace. Like if you want to use TextMeshPro you should put 'using TMPro' at the top of the script.

Comment: Yes, but the issue still stands: ProbeReferenceVolume.cs is immutable and contains an error by default. Can't edit it and add any namespaces or definitions (though even trying didn't work in VS). No idea what to do. This issue is there by default on any new URP project I create.